# Blazor, IdentityServer4 and Multi-Tenancy

Tags: identityserver4, multi-tenant

I'm building a `Blazor` App that uses `IdentityServer4` for `authentication` and authorization to a `WebAPI`. My goal is to set this up in a way where clients share the same app and api instances but have a separate database. So, all users would see "https://app.domain.com" but they would be presented with data from their database `"tenant_1_db",` `"tenant_2_db"`, `etc`...

I've read some stuff on using acrvalues from IdentityServer4 to store the tenant value of the user but not sure if this is the most appropriate way to manage this?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Structure below:
    "https://app.domain.com" - Blazor App
    "https://identity.domain.com" - IdentityServer4 (Identity_DB)
    "https://api.domain.com" - WebAPI - (Tenant_1_DB, Tenant_2_DB)